# Double checking: passing out internal reference from member function

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

If I have

```
//test.hpp
class iA
{
public:
  virtual ~iA(){}
  virtual void foo() const = 0;
};


class A1 : public iA
{
public:
  virtual ~A1(){}
  A1(){}
  virtual void foo() const;
};

class A2 : public iA
{
public:
  virtual ~A2(){}
  A2(){}
  virtual void foo() const;
};

class B
{
public:
  B(int a);
  B(const std::string& s);

  ~B() {if (a_) {delete a_; a_ = 0;}}

  const iA& a() const
  {
    return *a_;
  }

  void foo() const;


private:
  iA* a_;
};
```

And I wrote the python wrapper below:

```
struct iAWrap : iA, boost::python::wrapper<iA>
{
  void foo() const
  {
    this->get_override("foo");
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libtest)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);

    class_<iAWrap, boost::noncopyable>("iA")
      .def("foo",pure_virtual(&iA::foo))
        ;

    class_<B>("B",init<int>())
        .def(init<std::string>())
        .def("foo", &B::foo)
        .def("a", &B::a, return_internal_reference<1>())//line I have a question about
        ;
}
```

The return_internal_reference<1> binds the lifetime of the A reference returned to the invisible "self" argument of B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has always helped me to think of it as though the object being returned (`A`) *extends* the lifetime of its owning object (`B`) to be at least as long as the returned object (`A`).

The [`return_internal_reference`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_internal_reference.html) documentation describes the `owner_arg`:

> The index of the parameter which contains the object to which the reference or pointer is being returned. If used to wrap a member function, parameter `1` is the target object (`*this`).

In the original code, the `owner_arg` is explicitly set to `1` indicating that the `this` object (`B`) in the member function (`&B::a`) invocation is the object that contains the returned object (`iA`).

The lifetime behavior effects is documented in [`with_custodian_and_ward_postcall`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/with_custodian_and_ward.html#with_custodian_and_ward_postcall-spec), which states:

> The *ward* object will not be destroyed until after the *custodian* [...]

The `return_internal_reference` documentation's class synopsis simplifies the actual inheritance chain:

```cpp
template <std::size_t owner_arg = 1, class BasePolicy_ = default_call_policies>
struct return_internal_reference
    : with_custodian_and_ward_postcall<0, owner_arg, BasePolicy_>
{
  // ...
};
```

The `return_internal_reference` struct:

- explicitly provides `0` as the `custodian`, setting the return object (`iA`) of `postcall()` as the *custodian* in the relationship.
- passes the `owner_arg` (`return_internal_reference` defaults to `1`) as the `ward`, setting the `*this` object (`B`) as the *ward* in the relationship.

Hence, the `B` *ward* object will not be destroyed until after the `iA` *custodian* object.

---

Here is a complete simple example demonstrating this behavior:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo()  { std::cout << "Foo()" << std::endl; }
  ~Foo() { std::cout << "~Foo()" << std::endl; }
};

class Bar
{
public:
  Bar()  { std::cout << "Bar()" << std::endl; }
  ~Bar() { std::cout << "~Bar()" << std::endl; }
  Foo& foo() { return foo_; }
private:
  Foo foo_;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<Foo>("Foo");
  python::class_<Bar>("Bar")
    .def("foo", &Bar::foo, python::return_internal_reference<>())
    ;
}
```

Interactive Python:

```python
>>> import example
>>> bar = example.Bar()
Foo()
Bar()
>>> foo = bar.foo()
>>> del bar
>>> del foo
~Bar()
~Foo()
```

Note that the lifetime of the `bar` *ward* object was extended to be at least as long as the `foo` *custodian* object.